Android app: encyclopedia of martial arts
The Judo Reference app is just a great app. It lets you view all judo moves, according to belt color, with pictures, explanations, and names, and the whole app is overall very pleasant to use, user friendly, and intuitive (and, it is even complete).
Examples of other marital arts include karate, viet-vo-dao, ju-jitsu, and others (I am not an expert, but I know that there exist very many. I would be glad to find out what these are, and how they differ, via an app).
However, I am now looking for an encyclopedia app which would work as a comparative work of all known marital art types, how their moves are, how the martial arts types differ, what the history of the martial art is and how it developed, where it is mostly practiced or where it has gained momentum with links to practice centers (which could be, movingly, updated, by centers logging in, subscribing, and providing information, via marital art center type and information), and a list of what some lines of thought and things to keep in mind and things to help concentrate, reason about philosophy, and practice, are, in each marital art case. There could even be an encyclopedia section on settings, information, with ground types (or settings), and instruments used, information (and, how to use instruments, efficiently, and how to practice with them, without getting hurt (or, even, how to build them, or, how they are, or, can, be built).
There could be several sections and connections between the app and history and philosophy.
But there could be also sections on information crunch and health sections.
In each case, one could also click on various arts and see how they intact, what they have in common, and what various "fusion" arts, that have come about, could be (and what they consist of).
There could also be a section on parallel or commentary arts such as meditation or yoga.
